# MySQL error "Cannot drop index" when trying to ADD INDEX

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm running this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `loan`
ADD INDEX `Customer ID_Bank Account` (`Customer ID`, `Bank Account`);
```

and getting this error:

```
Error in query (1553): Cannot drop index 'Customer ID': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

I know very well why the index on "Customer ID" cannot be deleted; it's needed in several foreign keys.  The question is, why would an `ADD INDEX` statement EVER try to drop an index?

(And how can I get it to stop trying to drop that index while I'm trying to add the new one?)

My MySQL version string is "5.5.60-MariaDB".

Comment: Can't you use `CREATE INDEX` instead? In MySQL the word of "index" is somewhat misleading. They usually mean a "key". Do you need a new key (unique constraint) or a new index (for fast searches)?

Comment: never use space in names for columns or constraints

Comment: @nbk I like my column names to be the same as my form field labels when possible. In any case, you should only be talking about the spaces if the spaces are causing my problem, which they probably aren't.

Comment: i teste with my database and thee are no spaces un the names and so there are no need for quotes of any kind, and that works perfecty add KEY ADD INDEX ....and it is bad practise

Comment: @nbk I tested with some other databases too, spaces and all, and they also worked perfectly.  This database is unusual somehow, and I'm looking for someone to explain how an outcome like this is even possible - not wild guesses as to what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: @TheImpaler Pardon me, `CREATE INDEX` did NOT work.  I wrote another comment stating that, but it was deleted somehow (by a moderator I suppose?).  The `CREATE INDEX` statement completed without error, but instead of creating an index, it dropped the table.

Comment: add or crea<tig an index doesn't delete an old one, so the errro lies within your database. First whta to is eleiminate everything that is a potential error and then see if it still happens, also you never told us your version of your database. , and so we don't know if there is already an update fpr that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [MariaDB bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18320), when MySQL creates an index *as part of* creating a foreign key, it marks that index to be automatically deleted later should it be made redundant by another index created later.

Ideally this deletion of the "redundant" index would never fail, but apparently MySQL has a bug here.  Fortunately, there's a workaround:

```
ALTER TABLE `loan`
DROP INDEX `Customer ID`,
ADD INDEX `Customer ID` (`Customer ID`);
```

Drop and recreate the offending index in a single statement.  So long as the index name is exactly the same before and after, MySQL doesn't complain about the index being dropped; and the explicit create on the index causes MySQL to remove the "automatically delete this index" indicator.

Answer (score 0):

The messaging of MySQL is usually misleading to me.

In relational databases foreign keys can only point to:

- Primary keys, or
- Unique Constraints. That's it.

In this case you are not talking about the primary key, so what you need is a unique constraint (that may be called `UNIQUE INDEX` or `UNIQUE KEY` in MySQL lingo). The word *index* is usually used to deal with fast data access, but not with referential integrity.

**Note**: Some indexes can be used to ensure uniqueness rules, that SQL constraints cannot deal with, particularly partial unique indexes. But that's another story.

You can create the unique constraint as:

```
alter table loan
add constraint uq1 unique (`Customer ID`, `Bank Account`);
```

A full running example could be:

```
create table loan (
  id int primary key not null,
  `Customer ID` int,
  `Bank Account` int
);

alter table loan
add constraint uq1 unique (`Customer ID`, `Bank Account`);

create table item (cid int, acc int, val int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (cid, acc) 
    references loan (`Customer ID`, `Bank Account`)
);

insert into loan (id, `Customer ID`, `Bank Account`) values (1, 20, 30); -- succeeds
insert into loan (id, `Customer ID`, `Bank Account`) values (2, 21, 31); -- succeeds
insert into loan (id, `Customer ID`, `Bank Account`) values (3, 20, 30); -- fails!
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4U33jj85Zii2zLmBXeCRLb/0).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't address my question.  I'm not looking for general information about creating indexes and/or foreign keys; I know the general information.  I'm looking for information on why MySQL would do something rather bizarre, on a database that's probably unusual in some fashion.

Comment: @Brilliand I hear you. No worries.